# What is the quickest way to switch between an active window 8 app and desktop app

Tags: windows, windows-8

for example: If I am currently using the window 8 Skype app.

- I need to click on the window button on my keyboard to bring up the
  start window.
- Click on the desktop icon on there to go to desktop
- open my desktop app.

Where before in window 7 I can simply alt-tab between different apps that were opened. 
Is there such simple way in window 8 to toggle between window 8 app and desktop app? Or do I need to install a "desktop" version of the apps instead.

Comment: `Windows Key + D` is always helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can push your mouse to the top left corner of your screen and left click on your mouse. If that is the only app that you have open or. You can press the Windows Key+Tab. That should switch you as well.